# MySQL shell displaying results into something like "less"

Tags: mysql, linux, shell

Running the following command in a remote login attempt in a MySQL shell.

```
show variables;
```

The query only shows the last 50 or so variables out of 233.  I would like the result to be scrollable so that I can review all of the variables.  Something like a redirect to 'less.'

As it is, I am stumped.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try using the following command to set a "less"-type of behavior in the MySQL command line:

`pager less`

Also, this behavior can be turned off by using this command:

`pager`

(*Note: This might not work on every flavor of MySQL... for more information, [check the docs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/4.1/en/mysql-command-options.html#option_mysql_pager).*)

Comment: excellent; appreciate it.  It's always the simple stuff that's the hardest to figure out.

Comment: @user2157666 happens to me all the time :)

Comment: Also, the `less` applet (or whatever pagination handler you choose) has to be installed on your machine. It is not always there, especially on some small custom distributions.